# Passing by reference from a return value gives me an error, when it does not if that same value is assigned to variable

Tags: c++, gcc

i have those 2 pieces of code, which seem to be equivalent to me, but one gives me a compiler error and the other does not.

I return a `QString` from one function and pass by reference to another one:

```
void takesAQString(QString& s){}
QString returnsAQString(){QString s = "Hello"; return s;}

QString s = returnsAQString();
QString ss = "Hello";
takesAQString(s); //this compiles without error
takesAQString(ss); //this too
takesAQString(returnsAQString()); //this gives me an error
```

This gives me `error: no matching function to call '...takesAQString(QString)'` and `note: candidates are: ... takesAQString(QString&)`

Well the error itself is pretty clear, but to me the above 3 ways of passing in the `QString` seem to be 100% equivalent to me. What am i missing?

Comment: Temporary cannot bind to non const lvalue reference. (you may want `void takesAQString(const QString& s)`).

Comment: That's it. Maybe the answer juanchopanza pointed out might explain why this is.